# Derivative over time of an integral over the space in the context of Brownian motions

Tags: derivatives, indefinite-integrals, brownian-motion

in the context of Brownian motions I have to solve this expression here:
$\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}\int^{\infty}_{x}{g_t(y)dy}$

where $g_t(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{\frac{-y^2}{2t}}$.
I tried to swap derivative and integral and I came up with

$$\int^{\infty}_{x}{\frac{-1}{2t}g_t(y)+\frac{y^2}{2t^2}g_t(y)dy}$$
I know that the result should be $$\frac{x}{t}g_t(x)$$ but I don't know why.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try to use the fact that $g_t(y)$ solves the heat equation.

Comment: You should find that the end result is $\frac x{\color{red}{2}\,t}g_t(x)\,.$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Let me put the spoiler here for other readers. \begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g_t(y)&=\frac12\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}g_t(y)\,,\\
\frac12\int_x^{+\infty}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}g_t(y)\,dy&=-\frac12\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g_t(y)\Bigg|_{y=x}\stackrel{\text{quite obviously}}{=}\frac x{2t} g_t(x)\,.
\end{align}